# How to reduce eye strain which comes only when watching animations and cartoons?

Tags: personal-care, light, eyesight

My eyes hurt sometimes. Though I watch a lot of videos on YouTube like educational, T.V. series, documentaries but I notice my eyes getting strained and tired only when I am watching cartoons, animations or animated educational videos, etc. I think the cartoons are always by standard much more brighter could be a reason for it(though I am myself not pretty sure about it, but I think it could be the reason, maybe the frames per second could be another explanation which is high in most cartoons and animations). I believe my eyes are strained whenever I watch too much but I feel the strain predominantly only after watching cartoons and animations. Could anybody give me an advice?

If the problem is cartoons are brighter than other things, what could be the solution?

Comment: Animation is a much lower frame rate than live action (animation is done "on twos" or "on threes," meaning one drawn frame for two or three actual frames--thus, lower frame rate).

Comment: I just had a crazy idea. I figured (please stop me if this is too radical), try not to watch any cartoons or animations for a while to grant your eyes some rest?

Comment: As a parent of young teenagers my advice is to go outside and do something active. Also: clean your room ;)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid eye-strain:

- Make sure to blink frequently. Your brain doesn't let you blink when you are watching something intently.
- Make sure to look around and away from the screen frequently. Changing eye-focus prevents eye-strain.
- Try change the contrast/brightness of the screen. To do this:
- Use controls on your monitor, or
- Use *Fn-buttons* on your laptop keyboard, or
- Use *Color management* from your Control Panel

  - Search for *color* in the control panel / settings

Summary tip: Try walking around the room while watching; this will help you and your eyes feel better.